# change tweet widget <div>'s to <li>'s

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, jcarousel

[i've created a live tweet feed onto my site which a want wrapped in a carousel. the challenge i'm facing is converting the twitter API feed divs into "li's" so each twitter feed is displayed in a seperate li's.

I've managed to write up some javascript, in attempts to achieve what i'm trying to do however what i've created have proven to be unsuccessful. Is there anyone on here that can correct me where i'm going wrong?

http://thisiswired.com/test/test.html

```
<div class="carousel3">
    <ul id="tweets">
    <li class="a"> <a href="#">
        <script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
    </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
$('.twtr-reference-tweet').remove();

// Change the <div>s to <li>s
$('.twtr-tweet').each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith('<li id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" class="'+$(this).attr('class')+'">' + $(this).html() + '</li>');
});

// Change the parent <div> to <ul> and wrap it in a <div> ready to apply the carousel
$('.twtr-tweets').replaceWith('<div id="carouselId"> <ul class="twtr-tweets">'+$('.twtr-tweets').html()+'</ul></div>');

new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 20,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: 'transparent',
      color: 'transparent'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#000000',
      color: '#ffffff',
      links: '#ffffff'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('thisiswired').start();
```

Comment: Post the relevant HTML and Javascript code into the question (and make sure it's formatted correctly so it's readable), please.

Comment: Data from Twitter comes in JSON format, so you must have some code that is placing it into DIVs. Can you modify *that* code, instead of post-processing?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where you went wrong, but the elegant way to convert a div to an li is to add `.twtr-tweet{display:list-item;}` to your CSS.

In CSS, the `display` option lets us make `div`s effectively `span`s, `tr`/`td`s, `table`s, and a host of other things. And not just *from* `div`, lots of other tags (like `span`) can be modified this way.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: and has this worked for you, bcos it hasn't worked for me mate

Comment: Yep. But on your website http://thisiswired.com/test/css/twitterApi.css line 23 overrides this. Your original method is fine, you've got a syntax error somewhere preventing your code from running.

Comment: @Nate_tyrone Anyways, what's the final result you want? Making all `div`s into `li`s will keep them as boxes, but they may have dots next to them. The style information will still control the lis.

Comment: I managed to run you code by myself through a console, and it had the desired effect on the HTML, but there was no visible change. But your script wasn't working in the way it was placed. Note that this script should be loaded only *after* the divs are completely loaded. If the `div`s are being loaded after `$(document).ready`, then you can't use `$(document).ready` for loading this script. You may load the script in this manner, but it must wait till the divs have been loaded.

Comment: Besides, you have a few syntax errors on the page, check those out.